# NextJS API get response

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to fetch a message from /api pages on NextJS, how do I get the sent response from API to front end?

Example API:

```js
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
}
```

My API call on front end:

```js
    useEffect(() => {

        fetch("/api/hello",{method: "GET"}).then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
        })

    }, [])
```

Response I'm getting:

[image]

Why is the name 'John Doe' not appearing here?

When I was on create-react-app, I fetch APIs with axios and console logging response.data gives all the data sent from res.send from backend, but here on NextJS, it doesn't appear on API response

Comment: You need to call the appropriate method of the response object to get the data, and this is well covered both here on Stack Overflow and on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: @JaredSmith thanks so much bro! the first comment solved my problem.